# Regular expression to march all STRING_DIGIT[_?]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which could be ABC123_1 or ABC123_1_CBA321_2.
Basically we are talking about

```
[[:alnum:]]+_\d
```

which could be repeated several times. However, all the instances are concatenated with one underscore **_**, if more than one instance is present.

How can I match all of the instances in javascript, still using **^** and **$** to delimit the string?

- ABC123_1 ==> ['ABC123_1]
- ABC123_1_CBA321_2 ==> ['ABC123_1', 'CBA321_2']
- ABC123_1_CBA321_2_AA12_3 ==> ['ABC123_1', 'CBA321_2', 'AA12_3']

Thanks ;-)

Comment: What regex flavor? PyPi Python, .NET and Boost can handle that.

Comment: What do you mean with flavor? I need to do it in JS.

Comment: In JS, you will need to add more code to do that. Just regex won't suffice.

Comment: Then you want the *JS flavoured* regex...

Comment: Use a regex `/[^\W_]+_\d/`

Comment: @Mauro: I think the answer below is the best you can get with JS regex.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, the following could work:

```
regex = /[a-z0-9]{2,}_\d/gi;

> regex.match("ABC123_1_CBA321_2_AA12_3") 
< ["ABC123_1", "CBA321_2", "AA12_3"]
```